# Admob Native Banner

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to implement `Admob Native Banner` in one of the my application with `recyclerview`, its position based advertisement. I have marked that most of the time advertise is not available for native banner so I am not getting ads, I am planning to make concept for load ads like if native ad is available then we will show native banner and if native banner is not available then we can request and load `smart banner` ? I must confirm that we can load smart banner as position based replacement of native ads ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best on the NativeExpressAdView to add a listener to see if it loads

```
mNativeExpressAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
         super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
         //add didn't load so hide and revert to a smart banner by adding one in
         mNativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
});
```

You could then programatically add a smart banner in or have one in the xml view that you just toggle the visibility on.